# Howto correct set the regex to substitute multiline variable placeholder with perl

Tags: regex, perl, template-meta-programming

I'm writing complex configuration files for a data transformation tool with Perl 5.20.

The configuration file has placeholders for several aspects at load time and runtime encapsulating some [path code](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::DPath) like

```
# Load time placeholder example
CONFIG: NAME ${/path/pos/*/test/*[123] == 'ABC' }

# Runtime placeholder example
COLUMN: CSV_NAME STRING DEFAULT :{./CSV_FIRST}
```

For some reason it should work also on multi line expressions.

I've written scanner using `Text::ParseWord`, the standard separator `\s+` and want to escape the placeholder expressions before splitting the data line(s) into single words by `base64` encoded expressions not containing `\s+`. The expressions are also the keys for the subsequent data substitution.

The escaping is driven by a pattern match defined by (...see code below):

```perl
 my @pat = $line =~ /([^\\]\Q$pfx\E\{[^\Q$pfx\E\{\}]+\})/gs;
```

Which IMO defines a multi line pattern `${...}` when I use `$pfx = '$'` for example, but masks (escapes) `\${...}` expressions.

#### Question

I'm struggling a while with the inner part of the pattern `...` and get `[^\Q$pfx\E\{\}]+` to work, but have the feeling that is not the correct one, because

1. it includes only the symbols set not to use,
2. but not the sequence of the outer part,
3. to prevent nested expressions for example.

What is the right expression to do this?

### Test routine

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;

use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings 'once';
no warnings 'experimental';
no warnings 'experimental::signatures';

my $line =
'# test data
 This are:
 1. ${/multiline/used/*[3]
      = "12345"}
 2. ${/single/line/compile/time/pattern/*[3]}
 3. ${/single/line/runtime/pattern/x == 1234}
 4. ${/multi/line/runtime/pattern \
      defer/1 \
      defer/2 \
      defer/3
     }
 5. ${//PG.GRM/*[
        key eq "TEST.VAR"
       ]}
';

sub testSpacedPlaceHolder($pfx, $line) {
    my %match;
    
    my @pat = $line =~ /([^\\]\Q$pfx\E\{[^\Q$pfx\E\{\}]+\})/gs;
    my %seen = ();
    my @uniq = grep { ! $seen{$_} ++ } @pat;    
    for my $key (@uniq) {
        my $hkey=$pfx.encode_base64($key);
        $hkey =~ s/\n//g;
        my $var = substr($key, 3, -1);
        $match{$hkey}= [ $var, $key ];
        $line =~ s/\Q$key\E/$hkey/g;
    }
    # Test the output ------------------------------
    my $cnt = 0;
    print "\nRESULT:\n";
    for my $key (sort keys %match) {
        $cnt++;
        my ($var, $orig) = @ { $match{$key} };
        print "---- $cnt ----\n";
        print "ORG: $orig\n";
        print "VAR: $var\n";
        print "ESC: $key\n";

    }
    print "\nLINE:\n$line\n";
    return ($line, \%match);
}

testSpacedPlaceHolder('$', $line);
```

### Result

```
/usr/bin/env perl "test-strings.pl"

RESULT:
---- 1 ----
ORG:  ${/multi/line/runtime/pattern \
      defer/1 \
      defer/2 \
      defer/3
     }
VAR: /multi/line/runtime/pattern \
      defer/1 \
      defer/2 \
      defer/3
     
ESC: $ICR7L211bHRpL2xpbmUvcnVudGltZS9wYXR0ZXJuIFwKICAgICAgZGVmZXIvMSBcCiAgICAgIGRlZmVyLzIgXAogICAgICBkZWZlci8zCiAgICAgfQ==
---- 2 ----
ORG:  ${/multiline/used/*[3]
      = "12345"}
VAR: /multiline/used/*[3]
      = "12345"
ESC: $ICR7L211bHRpbGluZS91c2VkLypbM10KICAgICAgPSAiMTIzNDUifQ==
---- 3 ----
ORG:  ${/single/line/compile/time/pattern/*[3]}
VAR: /single/line/compile/time/pattern/*[3]
ESC: $ICR7L3NpbmdsZS9saW5lL2NvbXBpbGUvdGltZS9wYXR0ZXJuLypbM119
---- 4 ----
ORG:  ${/single/line/runtime/pattern/x == 1234}
VAR: /single/line/runtime/pattern/x == 1234
ESC: $ICR7L3NpbmdsZS9saW5lL3J1bnRpbWUvcGF0dGVybi94ID09IDEyMzR9
---- 5 ----
ORG:  ${//PG.GRM/*[
        key eq "TEST.VAR"
       ]}
VAR: //PG.GRM/*[
        key eq "TEST.VAR"
       ]
ESC: $ICR7Ly9QRy5HUk0vKlsKICAgICAgICBrZXkgZXEgIlRFU1QuVkFSIgogICAgICAgXX0=

LINE:
# test data
 This are:
 1.$ICR7L211bHRpbGluZS91c2VkLypbM10KICAgICAgPSAiMTIzNDUifQ==
 2.$ICR7L3NpbmdsZS9saW5lL2NvbXBpbGUvdGltZS9wYXR0ZXJuLypbM119
 3.$ICR7L3NpbmdsZS9saW5lL3J1bnRpbWUvcGF0dGVybi94ID09IDEyMzR9
 4.$ICR7L211bHRpL2xpbmUvcnVudGltZS9wYXR0ZXJuIFwKICAgICAgZGVmZXIvMSBcCiAgICAgIGRlZmVyLzIgXAogICAgICBkZWZlci8zCiAgICAgfQ==
 5.$ICR7Ly9QRy5HUk0vKlsKICAgICAgICBrZXkgZXEgIlRFU1QuVkFSIgogICAgICAgXX0=
```

### Edit

Assuming I have a script that defines some kind of configuration:

```
MAGIC: MAGIC.TYPE

CONTAINER: NAME BEGIN

DEFINE: VAR1 'USER.NAME'
DEFINE: VAR2 '65789'

INTERNAL.CONTAINER: INTERNAL.NAME BEGIN

    TAG1: 'ABCDEF'
    TAG2: ${/NAME/VAR1}

    # Unwanted nested variant 
    TAG3: ${/NAME/VAR1 ${/NAME/VAR2} }

    # Valid runtime interpolation variant
    TAG4: "${/NAME/VAR1}/:{NAME.KEY}"
    
    # Valid runtime path variant but ignored
    TAG5: ${/NAME/VAR1/*/:{TEST{KEY}}

END.INTERNAL.NAME
 
END.NAME
```

I want to avoid the nested line

```perl
    # Nested variant 
    TAG3: ${/NAME/VAR1 ${/NAME/VAR2}}
```

for variable resolve reasons, but keep

```perl
    # Valid runtime path variant but ignored
    TAG5: ${/NAME/VAR2/*/:{TEST{KEY}}
```

because they are runtime driven.

My variant blocks TAG5 due to the simple sequence `[\$\{\}]+`.

Comment: *"the inner part of the pattern ... but have the feeling that is not the correct one"* Can you give an example of where the pattern fails? This could help clarify your question

Comment: Hm, the pattern does not fail but, because I take away all characters, but the inner pattern could also be `{}$`, `{$}` ... `$}{`. I only want to avoid a nested pattern like `${...}` for the inner part.

Comment: *"I only want to avoid a nested pattern like ${...}"* Why is it important to avoid a nested pattern? Can you give an example of such pattern? And the expected result

Comment: See: EDIT I'd like to distinguish design time patter (not nest-able) and runtime pattern (nesting OK) but the closing bracket `}` breaks my approach. I need to the exclusion   expression in the inner part semantically for ${...}.

Comment: *"I want to avoid the nested line"* : I think you can do this with recursive regexes, see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) for more information. But since you also want to include the recursive cases where there are no `$` in front of the `{` I guess it will become somewhat complicated to develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use a recursive regex to exclude nested versions of `${...}`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
my $str = <<'END_STR';
MAGIC: MAGIC.TYPE

CONTAINER: NAME BEGIN

DEFINE: VAR1 'USER.NAME'
DEFINE: VAR2 '65789'

INTERNAL.CONTAINER: INTERNAL.NAME BEGIN

    TAG1: 'ABCDEF'
    TAG2: ${/NAME/VAR1}

    # Unwanted nested variant
    TAG3: ${/NAME/VAR1 ${/NAME/VAR2} }

    # Valid runtime interpolation variant
    TAG4: "${/NAME/VAR1}/:{NAME.KEY}"

    # Valid runtime path variant but ignored
    TAG5: ${/NAME/VAR1/*/:{TEST{KEY}}}

END.INTERNAL.NAME

END.NAME
END_STR

my @matches;
while ($str =~ /(?:^|(?<!\\))
                   (?<G3>(?<G1> \$ \{ (?:
                       (?>(?:[^{}\$\\] | (?:\\.) |
                         (?<G2> \{ (?: (?>[^{}]+) | (?&G2))* \} ))
                           | (?<G4>(?&G1))))* \}))/msxg) {
    next if defined $+{G4}; # skip nested matches
    push @matches, $+{G3};
}
print Dumper(\@matches);
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '${/NAME/VAR1}',
          '${/NAME/VAR1}',
          '${/NAME/VAR1/*/:{TEST{KEY}}}'
        ];
```

Notice that the results include TAG2, TAG4, and TAG5, but not TAG3.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I see from my example, that I have to care about the balanced curly braces.